# When sliding sprite, if sprite disappears off the side, it will wrap around to the opposite side?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, infinite-loop

When sliding sprite, if sprite disappears off the side, i want to make it wrap around to the opposite side but I do not know how to do this while the sprite is simultaneously being pushed off one side i want the other bit that you can't see to appear on the opposite side like a loop some sort of wormhole thing.

here is my code so far but it crashes and it only transports the sprite once the whole of the sprite disappears of the side. Loop also needs to run as an infinite loop until someone quits the app.

```
        for (int i =0; i<16; ++i) {
        MyNode *currentSprite = [c1array objectAtIndex:i];
        if (currentSprite.contentSize.height>=320 || currentSprite.position.y-currentSprite.contentSize.height/2<=0 ){
            MyNode *Bsprite = currentSprite;
            MyNode *Tsprite = currentSprite;
            Bsprite.scale = 1.0;
            Tsprite.scale = 1.0;

            if(currentSprite.position.y >=253){
            Bsprite.position = ccp(currentSprite.position.x,-35);
                [self addChild:Bsprite];
                Bsprite.visible = TRUE;
            }
            if (currentSprite.position.y <=0) {
                Tsprite.position = ccp(currentSprite.position.x,324);
                [self addChild:Tsprite];
                Tsprite.visible = TRUE;
            }
            MyNode *isChanging;
            if ((Tsprite.visible == TRUE && currentSprite.visible == TRUE) || (Bsprite.visible == TRUE && currentSprite.visible == TRUE)) {
                isChanging = TRUE;
            }
            if (isChanging == FALSE) {
                [self removeChild:Tsprite cleanup:YES];
                [self removeChild:Bsprite cleanup:YES];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do with one sprite. But you can have two sprites. In common situation when your sprite is sliding along the screen only one sprite will be visible. But when it reaches the border the second one will be visible too. When the second one will completely enter the screen - remove (or hide) the first one.

The best way to implement this is to create a CCNode subclass that will contain first and second sprite and will swap them if required. In this way all your logic will be very simple. You will just work with one CCNode (subclass) and will not think about swaping sprites - it will be done automatically by your class

**EDIT**

```
@interface MyNode : CCNode
{
    CCSprite *sprite1;
    CCSprite *sprite2;
    CCSprite *currentSprite;
    bool isChanging; //indicates that now two sprites are visible
}
@end
```

Comment: @Andrew thanks i was thinking i would have to use two sprites

Comment: @Andrew, i need a bit of help starting off as i'm not sure about how to go about making a ccnode subclass i know that i make it inherit from an object but i don't really know what to do.

Comment: @Andrew, i'm getting an error at MyNode, I'll post my header(.h) file, the sprite1-15 are al the sprites on the page, bSprite and Tsprite are the is the equivalent of sprite 1 and sprite2 on your version.

Comment: @Dangermouse: I don't see @interface and @end keywords in your code

Comment: @Andrew, i typed them in and it made no difference. When i leave the keywords out I get less errors as well.

Comment: @Dangermouse: Then i suggest you to study objective-c because you can't declare an interface without a keyword @interface - this is the basic thing in objective-c

Comment: @Andrew, i need a bit of help with replacing the sprite, i've edited the code in the question.

Comment: @Dangermouse: i suggest you to ask a new question and explain your problem better