# creating a loop with multiple sprites?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone, css-sprites

i've got a column of sprites as one sprite goes off the screen i want the same sprite to wrap around the opposite side so that two sprites are showing simultaneously, as one moves of the screen the other comes onto the screen and the other sprite that goes off is no longer visible. I was told to make a ccnode in which to do everything here is my code so far, but none of it works so i think i will need to start from scratch again.
Here is a link to my last question on this for more info: [When sliding sprite, if sprite disappears off the side, it will wrap around to the opposite side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224039/when-sliding-sprite-if-sprite-disappears-off-the-side-it-will-wrap-around-to-th)

here is my code anyways:

```
    for (int i =0; i<16; ++i) {
        MyNode *currentSprite = [c1array objectAtIndex:i];
        if (currentSprite.contentSize.height>=320 || currentSprite.position.y-currentSprite.contentSize.height/2<=0 ){
            MyNode *Bsprite = currentSprite;
            MyNode *Tsprite = currentSprite;
            Bsprite.scale = 1.0;
            Tsprite.scale = 1.0;

            if(currentSprite.position.y >=253){
            Bsprite.position = ccp(currentSprite.position.x,-35);
                [self addChild:Bsprite];
                Bsprite.visible = TRUE;
            }
            if (currentSprite.position.y <=0) {
                Tsprite.position = ccp(currentSprite.position.x,324);
                [self addChild:Tsprite];
                Tsprite.visible = TRUE;
            }
            MyNode *isChanging;
            if ((Tsprite.visible == TRUE && currentSprite.visible == TRUE) || (Bsprite.visible == TRUE && currentSprite.visible == TRUE)) {
                isChanging = TRUE;
            }
            if (isChanging == FALSE) {
                [self removeChild:Tsprite cleanup:YES];
                [self removeChild:Bsprite cleanup:YES];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

BSprite and TSprite are pointers to the same object (currentSprite). You actually need two separate objects, either by cloning currentSprite or by creating another array in the same manner as c1array.

Comment: i wanted to start the code again as it's a complete mess, need a simpler way to allow this to happen as tsprite/bsprite comes onto the page they need to be touch enabled and when they go off, the sprite that went off must come back on again so i wanted someone to help me out from the beginning as my code has got too many problems everywhere.